# How can I copy one column to from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and my problem is this with a database called LogStats.

If I execute this query:

```
select *
from ExceptionRow
     inner join HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
where ExceptionRow.Message is null
      AND not HashFP.MessageFP is null
```

I got 126708 hits and it take 2.05 minutes. But optimizations is not my question.

I want to copy data from HashFP.MessageFP to ExceptionRow.Message without overwriting any data. I try this:

```
UPDATE ExceptionRow
SET Exceptionrow.Message = HashFP.MessageFP
FROM ExceptionRow 
     INNER JOIN HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
WHERE ExceptionRow.Message IS NULL
      AND NOT HashFP.MessageFP IS NULL
```

The result:

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1  The transaction log for database
>   'LogStats' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused,
>   see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

I tried this:

```
SELECT name,log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases
```

From the result

```
tempdb   ACTIVE_TRANSACTION
LogStats ACTIVE_TRANSACTION
```

How can I abort those active transactions so the task can be successful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How can I abort those active transactions so the task can be successful ?

You can't, because it's the `UPDATE FROM` transaction. 
You can either increase max size of the log file:

```
ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME
MODIFY FILE (NAME=LOG_FILE_NAME,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED);
```

Or you can try something like this:

```
WHILE EXISTS
(select *
from ExceptionRow
     inner join HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
where ExceptionRow.Message is null
      AND not HashFP.MessageFP is null
)
UPDATE TOP (1000) ExceptionRow
SET Exceptionrow.Message = HashFP.MessageFP
FROM ExceptionRow 
     INNER JOIN HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
WHERE ExceptionRow.Message IS NULL
      AND NOT HashFP.MessageFP IS NULL
```

IF the database has SIMPLE recovery model this should work, if FULL or BULK_LOAD you need also do backup of transaction log in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ExceptionRow SET Exceptionrow.Message = HashFP.MessageFP FROM ExceptionRow 
INNER JOIN HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
WHERE ExceptionRow.Message IS NULL AND HashFP.MessageFP IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE ExceptionRow SET Exceptionrow.Message = HashFP.MessageFP FROM ExceptionRow 
INNER JOIN HashFP ON ExceptionRow.Hash=HashFP.FingerPrintMD5
WHERE ExceptionRow.Message IS NULL
```

since you are going to update *ExceptionRow.Message* when null with *HashFP.MessageFP* we no need to bother whether HashFP.MessageFP have null in it..